# Current, voltage, and power interpretation

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law

I have been working with circuits a lot more lately and not just modeling them. I think I never had a good enough understanding of the fundamental theory of voltage, power, and current.

Voltage is energy (acting sort as pressure to move current) I know voltage can be measured anywhere as long as you have a point in respect to something.

Current is the movement of electrons. Power is generated by some load (e.g. a resistor). Current follows the path of least resistance, correct?

These things I understand. Can you measure current anywhere in a circuit? Or can current just be measured across a component? I guess I just get confused on the path current may take and how sometimes you may get a negative current. I don’t fully understand why this is. I don’t know understand what current delivers. Should I focus on KCL?

Comment: "Current follows the path of least resistance correct?" - No, current follows *all* possible paths in inverse proportion to the resistance of the paths.

Comment: You should definitely understand KVL and KCL - they are pretty basic laws, and you don't have to remember the mathematical form, but you do need to *understand* them.

Answer (score 5):

> Voltage is energy

No. A voltage difference tells you how much energy it would take to move a charged particle between two points.

But the voltage can be defined even if there is no particle, and therefore no electrostatic potential energy, present.

> Current is the movement of electrons

Current is the movement of any charged particle, whether it's electrons or protons.

The case of protons (or positively charged ions) becomes important in batteries and other electrolytes.

> Power is generated by some load

We usually say that power is generated by a power supply (or battery or generator, etc), and is *absorbed* by the load.

> Can you measure current anywhere in a circuit?

You can measure current wherever there is current flowing.

In a simple supply + load circuit, the current will be the same anywhere in the circuit. When the circuit is more complicated, with multiple branches, then it might not be.

> sometimes you may get a negative current

A negative current is just a current in the opposite direction from whatever you assumed was the direction when you set up the problem.